# Why Terraform plan shows force replacement for existed ingress_rules ? if I add new ingress_rule in middle of list of ingress_rules variable in file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-security-group

I want to add new Ip to my load balancer ingress rule, so i'm adding the the new rule details block somewhere in middle of list variable named as app_ingress_rules in variables.tf file as shown below

**Variable.tf**

```
variable "app_ingress_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    from_port  = number
    to_port    = number
    protocol   = string
    cidr_block = string
  }))
  default = [
     {
         //existed ingress_rule1 details 
     },
     {
        //existed ingress_rule2 details 
     },
    
     #here i have added middle of list, new ingress_rule details.
     {
          protocol   = "tcp"
          from_port  = 443
          to_port    = 443
          cidr_block = "10.XXX.XX.XXX/32"
     },
     {
         //existed ingress_rule3 details 
     },
     {
        //existed ingress_rule4 details 
     }
```

above variable is getting used to create terraform resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_rules" in main.tf as shown below :

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_rules" {
  count = length(var.app_ingress_rules)

  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = var.app_ingress_rules[count.index].from_port
  to_port           = var.app_ingress_rules[count.index].to_port
  protocol          = var.app_ingress_rules[count.index].protocol
  cidr_blocks       = [var.app_ingress_rules[count.index].cidr_block]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.app_security_group.id
}
```

I expected this should work as normally as if I update list and add new element then this should not update content of any other elements, but I'm wondering how terraform work here, as I have not made any changes to details of other rules. but in terraform plan I see result as,

Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 2 to destroy.

here in EX: I have existed 4 ingress_rules and I added new at middle 3rd place then it will show

So here terraform destroying and recreating resources (ingress_rules),already existed in file at place below the newly added ingress_rule, along with creating new one in total. Why ?

Comment: Please add the output to the question.

Answer (score 1):

> how terraform work here

List have **order**. So if you are going to add a new element in a list in the middle, every other subsequent element will be assigned a **new index**.

For example, if you have `[1,2,3,4]`, and add `new2` element in a second position, other elements will have different index:

```
[1, new2, 2 will be 3, 3 will be 4, and 4 will be 5].
```

Change in the index will result in changes to resources. Thus you either have to add only elements **at the end** of the list, or use `map` (not `list`) with `for_each`. Maps do not have order.